# Reshape data wide-to-long, preserve variable order in `varying`

Tags: r, reshape

Data:

```
structure(list(Day = 1:13, Morning_1_id = structure(1:13, .Label = c("20180502-033-000005", 
"20180503-033-000005", "20180507-033-000006", "20180508-033-000005", 
"20180510-033-000005", "20180511-033-000005", "20180514-033-000005", 
"20180516-033-000005", "20180517-033-000001", "20180518-033-000005", 
"20180521-033-000006", "20180522-033-000005", "20180523-033-000005"
), class = "factor"), W = c(26.3666666666667, 26.4433333333333, 
26.2, 26.2866666666667, 26.43, 25.8733333333333, 26.64, 26.5233333333333, 
27.27, 26.6, 26.6966666666667, 26.27, 26.24), R = c(5.87258333333333, 
5.84598, 5.92537333333333, 6.02874666666667, 5.99018666666667, 
5.88347333333333, 5.25210666666667, 5.88159666666667, 5.87579333333333, 
5.92004, 5.68929, 5.89672, 5.93005), Morning_2_id = structure(1:13, .Label = c("20180502-033-000006", 
"20180503-033-000006", "20180507-033-000007", "20180508-033-000006", 
"20180510-033-000006", "20180511-033-000006", "20180514-033-000006", 
"20180516-033-000006", "20180517-033-000002", "20180518-033-000006", 
"20180521-033-000007", "20180522-033-000006", "20180523-033-000006"
), class = "factor"), W1 = c(26.3066666666667, 26.7233333333333, 
25.7866666666667, 27.12, 26.09, 25.82, 27, 26.2166666666667, 
26.5066666666667, 26.7233333333333, 26.8766666666667, 26.1733333333333, 
26.28), R1 = c(5.74259666666667, 5.91224, 5.85586333333333, 5.99682, 
5.99842333333333, 5.28803333333333, 5.88124333333333, 5.85363, 
5.85148333333333, 5.68396333333333, 5.68045666666667, 5.95528, 
5.84653666666667), Afternoon_1_id = structure(1:13, .Label = c("20180502-033-000024", 
"20180503-033-000015", "20180507-033-000020", "20180508-033-000020", 
"20180510-033-000011", "20180511-033-000017", "20180514-033-000011", 
"20180516-033-000012", "20180517-033-000012", "20180518-033-000011", 
"20180521-033-000012", "20180522-033-000011", "20180523-033-000011"
), class = "factor"), W2 = c(27.0733333333333, 26.2233333333333, 
26.4533333333333, 26.4166666666667, 26.0966666666667, 26.5833333333333, 
26.6266666666667, 26.2766666666667, 26.39, 25.5633333333333, 
25.1866666666667, 26.89, 25.17), R2 = c(5.95638, 5.97475666666667, 
5.78408, 5.91546333333333, 5.73866333333333, 5.79964666666667, 
5.87522333333333, 5.53540333333333, 5.85597666666667, 5.75941666666667, 
5.88696333333333, 5.56677, 5.50966666666667), Afternoon_2_id = structure(1:13, .Label = c("20180502-033-000025", 
"20180503-033-000016", "20180507-033-000021", "20180508-033-000021", 
"20180510-033-000012", "20180511-033-000018", "20180514-033-000012", 
"20180516-033-000014", "20180517-033-000014", "20180518-033-000012", 
"20180521-033-000013", "20180522-033-000012", "20180523-033-000012"
), class = "factor"), W3 = c(26.2233333333333, 26.1266666666667, 
25.7733333333333, 26.7933333333333, 26.8166666666667, 26.6633333333333, 
26.45, 25.7833333333333, 26.18, 26.9433333333333, 26.4666666666667, 
26.78, 26.3666666666667), R3 = c(5.83166, 5.88337, 5.93851, 5.96334666666667, 
5.83277, 5.92955, 5.92999333333333, 5.78252333333333, 5.79061666666667, 
5.61290333333333, 5.88305333333333, 5.88644666666667, 5.79076
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 13L))
```

I want to carry out wide to long conversion (in base R preferably) such that the Ids and the values of 'W' and 'R' get stacked day wise.

I use the reshape function as follows:

```
mydata<- reshape(new_data, direction='long', 
                 varying = c('Morning_1_id', 'W', 'R', 
                             'Morning_2_id', 'W1', 'R1', 
                             'Afternoon_1_id', 'W2', 'R2',
                             'Afternoon_2_id', 'W3', 'R3'), 
                 v.names = c('TId', 'W', 'R'),
                 timevar = c('W', 'R'), # differentiates
                 times = c('Morning1', 'Morning2', 'Afternoon1', 'Afternoon2'),
                 idvar = 'Day')
```

This leads to change in the order of column names. The column names are different from the values that they have. I want to correct this and then do the following steps.

What is the correct way to carry this out?

Comment: `reshape(new_data,matrix(2:ncol(new_data),3),idvar=1,dir="long",v.names = c('TestId', 'WBC', 'RBC'),
times = c('Morning1', 'Morning2', 'Afternoon1', 'Afternoon2'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your variables have different names, you will have to specify in the order you need them to be otherwise if they had difference in the numbering only then we could have used the `sep` argument or/and the `split` arguments in reshape. You just need to change the varying into a matrix as below indicating the positions:

```
mydata = reshape(new_data,matrix(2:ncol(new_data),3),idvar=1,dir="long",
                v.names = c('TId', 'W', 'R'), 
                times = c('Morning1', 'Morning2', 'Afternoon1', 'Afternoon2'))
head(mydata)
              Day       time                 TId        W        R
1.Morning1      1   Morning1 20180502-033-000005 26.36667 5.872583
2.Morning1      2   Morning1 20180503-033-000005 26.44333 5.845980
3.Morning1      3   Morning1 20180507-033-000006 26.20000 5.925373
4.Morning1      4   Morning1 20180508-033-000005 26.28667 6.028747
5.Morning1      5   Morning1 20180510-033-000005 26.43000 5.990187
6.Morning1      6   Morning1 20180511-033-000005 25.87333 5.883473
```

Answer (score 3):

It is the issue in the `varying`

```
varlist <- lapply(2:4, function(x) seq(x, ncol(new_data), by = 3))
out <- reshape(new_data, direction='long', varying=varlist, 
         v.names = c('TId', 'W', 'R'),
         times = c('Morning1', 'Morning2', 'Afternoon1', 'Afternoon2'), 
         idvar = 'Day')

head(out, 3)

#           Day     time                 TId        W        R
#1.Morning1   1 Morning1 20180502-033-000005 26.36667 5.872583
#2.Morning1   2 Morning1 20180503-033-000005 26.44333 5.845980
#3.Morning1   3 Morning1 20180507-033-000006 26.20000 5.925373
```

Comment: @VisheshShrivastav change the variable names in all post or none (i.e. rollback the change here). It's looking odd now!

Comment: Changed in all posts.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, the `melt()` function from the `data.table` package is able to reshape multiple measurements simultaneously. In addition, it allows to specify the column names as regular expressions which saves a lot of typing:

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(new_data), measure.vars = patterns("id$", "^W", "^R"),
     value.name = c("TId", "W", "R"))
```

> ```
>     Day variable                 TId        W        R
>  1:   1        1 20180502-033-000005 26.36667 5.872583
>  2:   2        1 20180503-033-000005 26.44333 5.845980
>  3:   3        1 20180507-033-000006 26.20000 5.925373
>  4:   4        1 20180508-033-000005 26.28667 6.028747
>  5:   5        1 20180510-033-000005 26.43000 5.990187
>  6:   6        1 20180511-033-000005 25.87333 5.883473
>  7:   7        1 20180514-033-000005 26.64000 5.252107
>  8:   8        1 20180516-033-000005 26.52333 5.881597
>  9:   9        1 20180517-033-000001 27.27000 5.875793
> 10:  10        1 20180518-033-000005 26.60000 5.920040
> 11:  11        1 20180521-033-000006 26.69667 5.689290
> 12:  12        1 20180522-033-000005 26.27000 5.896720
> 13:  13        1 20180523-033-000005 26.24000 5.930050
> 14:   1        2 20180502-033-000006 26.30667 5.742597
> 15:   2        2 20180503-033-000006 26.72333 5.912240
> ...
> ```

If required, the factor column "variable" can be replaced by a `time` column to get the same result as `reshape`:

```
melt(setDT(new_data), measure.vars = patterns("_id$", "^W", "^R"),
     value.name = c("TId", "W", "R"), variable.name = "time")[
       , time := c('Morning1', 'Morning2', 'Afternoon1', 'Afternoon2')[time]][]
```

> ```
>     Day       time                 TId        W        R
>  1:   1   Morning1 20180502-033-000005 26.36667 5.872583
>  2:   2   Morning1 20180503-033-000005 26.44333 5.845980
>  3:   3   Morning1 20180507-033-000006 26.20000 5.925373
>  4:   4   Morning1 20180508-033-000005 26.28667 6.028747
> ```

Here, the `time` values are explicitely given (like the `times =` parameter in  `reshape`). Alternatively, the `times` values can be created automatically using pattern matching and extracting:

```
melt(setDT(new_data), measure.vars = patterns("_id$", "^W", "^R"),
     value.name = c("TId", "W", "R"), variable.name = "time")[
       , time := na.omit(stringr::str_extract(names(new_data), ".*(?=_id$)"))[time]][]
```

> ```
>     Day        time                 TId        W        R
>  1:   1   Morning_1 20180502-033-000005 26.36667 5.872583
>  2:   2   Morning_1 20180503-033-000005 26.44333 5.845980
>  3:   3   Morning_1 20180507-033-000006 26.20000 5.925373
>  4:   4   Morning_1 20180508-033-000005 26.28667 6.028747
> ```

Here, the column names of `new_data` are searched for entries which end on `"_id` and the preceeding part of the string is extracted.